# ApexCharts: Inconsistent Rounded Border Behavior for Bar Chart Bars

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using the ApexCharts library to create a bar chart in my web application. I have configured the chart to have rounded borders for the bars using the borderRadius and borderRadiusApplication properties in the plotOptions. Here is the relevant configuration:

```
plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: false,
          columnWidth: '80%',
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderRadiusApplication: 'end',
        },
 }
```

The borderRadius property is set to 10, and the borderRadiusApplication is set to 'end', indicating that I want rounded borders for all bars.

However, I am encountering inconsistent behavior in the rendering of the rounded borders. While the rounded borders are applied correctly for some data sets, they are not applied consistently for others. Even though all data sets are expected to have rounded borders according to the configuration, some bars appear with sharp corners.

I have verified that the data is being passed correctly to the chart, and there are no errors in the data processing. Despite this, I cannot seem to achieve consistent rounded borders for all bars in the chart.

Could someone please provide insights into why this inconsistency is occurring and how I can ensure that all bars have rounded borders regardless of the data?

I have tried several approaches to troubleshoot the issue, including:

Double-checking the configuration settings: I ensured that the borderRadius and borderRadiusApplication properties are correctly set in the plotOptions configuration object for the bar chart.

Verifying the data: I confirmed that the data being passed to the chart is correctly formatted and does not contain any anomalies that could affect the rendering of the bars.

Experimenting with different configurations: I tried adjusting the values of the borderRadius and borderRadiusApplication properties to see if different settings would yield consistent results, but the issue persists.

Despite these efforts, I am still encountering inconsistent behavior with the rendering of the rounded borders for the bar chart bars. I expected all bars to have rounded borders as per the configuration settings, but some bars continue to display sharp corners instead.

Comment: There's not enough information. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In any case, with your configuration, each bar should have rounded borders, your altering `borderRadiusApplication` to `"end"` should have the effect that only two of the four corners of each bar are rounded. If the bars are stacked, you'd probably want to check [`borderRadiusWhenStacked`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar#borderRadiusWhenStacked) also.